# How to create a simple back up of all SQL Server 2008 R2 databases?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

If I am to create a very simple file based backup for my SQL Server would it be sufficient to just backup this folder?

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA
```

In other words if I have all the `.mdf` and `.ldf` files does this guarantee that I can restore all my databases in case of a server failure?

Thanks

Comment: The short answer to your question is no.  Your question is broad and difficult to answer in an easy to consume SO answer.  This may help: [SQL Server Backup and Restore](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/books/89519/), but you'll have to invest some time...

Comment: No, you can't just copy the mdf/ldf... do a real backup.  Try this, http://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-backup.html, its super easy.  Failing that, as suggested, try the DBA site -- we're not here for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I think JiggsJedi has the answre to my question:

http://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-backup.html

Anyone think this is not a programming one, feel free to move it where you think it belongs.

Best Regards